# Why is Keras throwing a ResourceExhaustedError?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, out-of-memory, gpu, keras

Keras is throwing a ResourceExhaustedError when training a convolutional autoencoder. I'm running the Tensorflow backend. The computer has both an Nvidia Tesla with 11 Gbs of memory and an Nvidia Quadro with 6 Gbs of memory. It seems like Tensorflow is using both GPUs? But I'm not too clear on that. Here is a minimal example of the code I'm using. In my example data is a numpy array of dimension=(100,1080,1920,1).

```
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(1080, 1920, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(data, data)
```

It seems like the GPUs are running out of memory. The autoencoder has 2625 variables. So that doesn't seem like enough to fill up the video ram. The array data has a size of 1600 MBs. So that also shouldn't fill up the video ram. I'm guessing the problem has something to do with nb_epoch and batch_size, but I'm not entirely clear on what those parameters do. Is there a way alter those parameters to fix my problem?

Comment: change 'Convolution2D' -> 'Conv2D' refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46032412

Answer (score 6):

Let's try to approximate how much of memory do you need for this network (despite the memory for parameters):

1. Input: 1600MB
2. First layer : ~ 1600MB * 16 / 4 = 6400MB (you have 16 times more channels and pooling layer - decreases the size of its input by 4).
3. Second layer : 6400MB (the input and the output of a layer is the same).
4. Third Layer : 25600MB (your are increasing the amount of data 4 times).
5. Output layer : 1600MB (the same as input).

You may see that third layer alone need more than 11GB of memory. Moreover - all forward values are stored - for a backpropagation algorithm - so in fact you need to sum up all of this values in order to obtain the final estimation of a memory need.

Answer (score 0):

change `Convolution2D` - > `Conv2D`
refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46032412/7148586